# Reclassify Slope using SAGA Raster Calculator

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, saga

I am looking for the right formula for reclassifying a slope raster. 
I need to switch the values 1 = bad, 10 = good to 1 = good, 10 = bad.
This Formula worked fine using the normal raster calculator: 
10 - %"Recoded@1"% + 1 
but I can't figure out the right formula using the SAGA or Gdal Raster Calculator for my processing model.
Any ideas!?

Comment: Do you need to switch just the values 1 and 10, or is it a continuous raster with value ranges between 1 and 10?

Answer (score 2):

A direct answer using **SAGA Raster Calculator**, would be `11- g1` (same as `10 - g1 + 1`).

Alternatively, `SAGA | Raster tools` **Invert grid** does the same job.

If we test with this example (sorry... I forgot to input `1`... and ended up with `10 - g1 + 2`).

[image]

---

Since OP's equation had been successful with QGIS raster calculator, I will not worry too much about continuous data. 
If input was continuous data (e.g. 1.23 - 10.00), the output gets funny and easily recognized.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using the SAGA Tool "Reclassify values". Here you can easily replace one value with another one (for example 1 with 10). Depending on your data, you might have to repeat the process several times to achieve the desired format